# Unable to create EC2 instance using Terraform when SCP tag policy is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, tags, terraform-provider-aws

We have the following service control policy (SCP) enabled, and even though I have admin access, I cannot create an EC2 instance using the Terraform code below.

**SCP policy**

```
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationSCP1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/CostCenter": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Terraform Code**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  profile = var.awsProfile
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      CostCenter = var.CostCenter
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.rhel-ami.id
  instance_type               = var.instanceType
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.subnet.id
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.kp.key_name
  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_role.screener-role.name

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.rootVolumeSize
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted = true
    kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.kmsKey.id
    tags = {
      CostCenter = var.CostCenter
    }
  }
```

**Error **

```
User arn:aws:sts::XXXXX:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_c7a8f842849299b9/XXXXX is not authorized to perform: ec2:RunInstances on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:XXXXX:volume/\* with an explicit deny in a service control policy.
```

When I remove the SCP, the same code works fine. So, I'm unsure why this Terraform code block is not working with SCP.

**NOTE**: I tried to create the instance directly in the AWS console with a similar tag, and it also works fine with the AWS CloudFormation method.

Could someone please help me to understand what mistake I'm making here? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your SCP only provisions us-east-1 and then you are trying to run an instance in us-west-2.

Comment: @Razumov No, I'm creating the resource exactly in us-east-1 region only. And I have also tried by making it valid for all regions but unfrotunately no success.

Comment: "is not authorized to perform: ec2:RunInstances on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:XXXXX:volume/" your words not his